# Как центрировать заголовок с элементами декора

Tags: позиционирование, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Фиксированный размер страницы по ширине — 900px.
Заголовок имеет следующий вид:

http://dropmefiles.com/BA9eg

Текст расположен по центру страницы, а полоса идет от одной границы к другой, то есть размер ее варьируется в зависимости от длины заголовка.
Можно ли реализовать подобное средствами html/css?

Спасибо!

Comment: @cratte, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли. Оптимальным вариантом из предложенных в ссылках, является этот: http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/vLwDf/1/

```css
h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
h1:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h1:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h1>This is a longer heading</h1>
```